# type + pointer array size + paranthesis meaning in syntax

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have a midterm in Saturday, so our teacher gave us the previous year's midterm to help. So there is a problem that I have trouble to understand. The question is 'fill the question marks so that program outputs the string 'accioccium'.

For who do not want to spend on solving, the answers are 1,2 and spell2.

So what is happening here? Especially, what is `char* (*a[3]) (char *, char *)`? I mean we are creating a char pointer array but what is that paranthesis at the end?

Also, `a[0] = fun1` is weird too. Yes, you can assign variables by functions. However, there is no parameter here for fun1 function. Let us say parameters are constant as *s and *p. But this time, what are they?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* fun1(char *s, char *p) {
    return s+strspn(s,p);}

char* fun2(char *s,char *p) {
    return strcat(s,p);}

char* fun3(char *s,char *p){
    return strstr(s,p);}


char* (*a[3]) (char *,char *);

int main(void) {
    int i;
    char spell1[10] = "accio";
    char spell2[10] = "aparecium";
    char* result;

    a[0] = fun1;
    a[1] = fun2;
    a[2] = fun3;

    result = (*a[?]) (spell1, "c");
    printf("%s",result);

    result = (*a[?]) (?, "c");
    printf("%s",result);

    return 0;}
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Especially, what is `char* (*a[3]) (char *, char *)` ? I mean we are creating a char pointer array but what is that paranthesis at the end?*

It's an array of 3 pointers to function that takes 2 arguments pointer to `char` and returns a pointer to `char`.

The assignment `a[0] = fun1` doesn't need the arguments, `fun` is not executed, only assigned to the compatible pointer `a[0]`, you only add the parameters later when you actually want to execute the function, which is done for example in the line `result = (*a[?]) (spell1, "c");`

Comment: Alright. So what happens a[0] = fun1? What are the parameters?

Comment: @ihatec That assignment still doesn't have parameters, you add them later when you actually call the fuction to be executed, which is what `result = (*a[?]) (spell1, "c");` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* (*a[3]) (char *,char *);
```

Starting from `a` and "going clockwise" or "picking things on the right first":

- `a`
- `[` is array
- `3])` of 3
- `(*` pointers
- `(...)` at end, to function
- `char *,char *` taking two parameters of type `char*`
- `char*` at the start, returning value of type `char*`

This matches signatures of `fun1`, `fun2` snd `fun3`. and indeed array is filled with pointers to these 3 functions. Function name without `()` means pointer to function, it does not call the function, and using `&` to get address is not needed.

Comment: I've always found "clockwise" vague, and preferred "things on the right have more priority than things on the left, unless parentheses are used".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, it's not perfect, I confess I resort to cdecl/cundecl for anything complex, just to be sure...